# Bootstrap 4 responsive images side by side same height

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put 3 images in Bootstrap 4. The problem is that the images are displayed one above the other and i want them to be displayed side by side.

Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br><span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br><span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br><span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess now that the code is correctly formatted you see where the problem is. As a hint I point you to `<div class="row">`.

Comment: A `row` has columns... each `row` is a new line... ergo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br>
            <span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br>
            <span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="placeBox">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Castelul Himeji<br>
            <span>Japonia</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, however you should explain what you did and why this is working :)

Comment: you were closing each row before starting `<div class="col-sm-4">` and I deleted that end div from code. Now its row start from top and at end div close.

Comment: You should edit your answer and put it in there, not as a comment

Comment: @ivanS95 I already  put all things in Answer. If you like my answer, please vote my answer and comments. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the one who made the question; I'm just letting you know that your answer should provide all the context for why your solution works in the body of the answer, not in the comments section, read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @IvanS95 sorry for any inconvenience. I didn't read above Name.